# How to send system messages in server side node.js in stream.io

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

I'm currently using stream.io and i want o send system messages for the backend.

I get this error message when i run the code down below
"oth secret and user tokens are not set. Either client.connectUser wasn't called or client.disconnect was called"

```
const streamChannel = streamClient.getChannelById('livestream', roomId, {});
    await streamChannel.sendMessage({
      text: `X joined the room`
  });
```

But when i try to .connect User, I get this error
"Please do not use connectUser server side. connectUser impacts MAU and concurrent connection usage and thus your bill."

What is the correct way of sending a system message to a room?

EDIT:
Getting I still keep getting this error. `Call connectUser or connectAnonymousUser before creating a channel` error

```
const serverClient = StreamChat.getInstance('key', 'key');
    const streamChannel = serverClient.channel('messaging', 'roomId');
    const {message} = await streamChannel.sendMessage({
      user_id: "system_user",
      text: `${user?.username} joined the room`,
      type: "system"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things happening here:

1. You are not using the correct connection code. Instead of the one for the client (as documented [here](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/node/init_and_users/?language=javascript#connecting-the-user)) you need to use the server-side connection (see [documentation](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/node/tokens_and_authentication/?language=javascript#generating-tokens)).

This is an example how to use the server-side code:

```js
// Initialize a Server Client
const serverClient = StreamChat.getInstance( api_key, api_secret);
// Create User Token
const token = serverClient.createToken(user_id);
```

And in order to send a message you can do it like this:

```js
const serverClient = StreamChat.getInstance('API_KEY', 'API_SECRET');
const channel = serverClient.channel('messaging', 'my-channel');
const { message } = await channel.sendMessage({
        user_id: 'john',
        text: 'X joined the room',
});
```

2. The second thing is that we updated the way you can send system messages. This is brand-new and currently being deployed, so you might have to wait shortly to have this available (let me know if it doesn't work yet for you) but then you can send system messages like this (building upon the previous code snippet):

```js
const { message } = await channel.sendMessage({
    user_id: 'john',
    text: 'X joined the room',
    type: 'system'
});
```

Hopefully this will be helpful to you, let me know if there's more questions!

Comment: I still keep getting this error. `Call connectUser or connectAnonymousUser before creating a channe` I edited the post of the code i am running above.

Comment: That is a different error now. If you want to create a new channel, there is the necessity to connect that to a certain user. So in that case you need to see which user needs to create the channel and authenticate them beforehand. 

Does that help?